# How to identify which cipher suites are in actual use?

Tags: azure, ssl, encryption

SSL Labs is great for identifying weak cipher suites.  But how do I know how many clients I affect if I remove them?

Is there a way to log on the server side which TLS version and cipher suite was being used for each connection?

Where do I look? Is this information available to the server software, or is it only available further down in the network stack?

**The specifics** 
The case that triggered this question is a BI tool (Qlik Sense) behind an Azure Gateway.

But when I thought about it, I can't remember seeing this kind of information in any other systems either.

To turn the question around:
If I follow SSL Labs recommendation, and only allow TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:  
What systems do I then exclude?
(How do I know if there are any at all, or lots of them?)

**Apology** 
*Sorry for a very open ended question. But I really don't know where to start looking.  Please let me know some key issues, and I can rephrase the question to more specific.*

Comment: Various servers have options to log various bits of information. What you want is the client's ciphersuite offering when no matching ciphersuite is found. For example, I don't see this as a possibility for [Apache mod_ssl](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html). Anything running a Java can be started with a command-line option `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to print tons of connection information including the information you seek. Something different than `all` will shrink the output considerably. You'll have to examine the docs for the servers your interested in.

Comment: Thank you, @PresidentJamesK.Polk. But is it only when there is no matching ciphersuite, that I need to get the offering from the client?  I mean, there might be a macth, even though the match might not be from the top of the list. Right?

Comment: Ok, I re-read the question and think I understand better. You want to keep your current ciphersuites for a while and look at the logs to see what might happen when you switch to offer just those two ciphersuites, correct? Still, the answer is basically the same, you need to log the list of ciphersuites that the client offers and see how often that list does not include one of your two.

Comment: That's right. But if the server-side code is third party, I have no way of changing what the server software logs. Turning on/off cipher suites happens in the OS layer (at least on Windows). I don't think Windows offers the ability to tap into this information (?).  Maybe one of the reverse proxies that are out there can do this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with windows but I think [this article on logging client information](https://www.microsoft.com/security/blog/2017/09/07/new-iis-functionality-to-help-identify-weak-tls-usage/) may be on point. I don't know exactly how you 3rd party app uses IIS (if at all) however. If all else fails there is always Wireshark/Tshark to log the packets including the client hello. You probably have to write some analysis code yourself to look for problem clients however.

Comment: Thank you @PresidentJamesK.Polk.  (Unfortunately?) the software is not based on IIS.  But very valuable article, nevertheless.   I guess Wireshark might be the way to go.  That might provide a solution that would work for many scenarios.